# How come my navigation control includes two bars one on the top and one on the bottom?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

In interface builder, I click on my tab bar controller and set the class of one of the tabs to  Navigation Controller. This should set the this tab to be a navigation controller.

However, I get an additional bar at the the bottom like a toolbar. Is this normal behavior? How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

In InterfaceBuilder, if you select the NavigationController item (usually in MainWindow.xib), you would notice a 'Show Toolbar' option in the Inspector that is selected.  Deselect it and hopefully it'll go away.